# Team Foundation Server Merge doesn't include files in target project

Tags: tfs

Using Team Foundation Server.

I'm merging my Feature-branch into my Dev-branch. It merges successfully. But, when I go into my Dev-branch solution all of the files that were added in the Feature-branch aren't "Included in the Project". It makes me search through all the folders to find them.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this the intentional merging functionality. I'd like all new files to automatically be included in the target project.

Or is there a way to only show the files/folders that aren't included in the project that way I don't have to search?

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't the answer anywhere. Any help would be included.

**EDIT**
I'm not sure what was happening. Maybe it caused issues when I merged one feature into dev, then made changes to dev and it's parent and checked them in. Is that known to cause issues?

To provide an update: After I just branched my freshly checked in DEV branch to a new feature, then made edits to the feature, checked in, and merge, everything worked as expected. All the new files were added to the dev solution (where I didn't have to manually include them)

Now I wonder where I went wrong initially.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with asp/mvc (I removed those tags). please tag your visual studio version, also give more detalis about what you have tried, perhaps add some screen shot etc, so people could help you.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for source control? If TFVC, are you using local or server workspaces?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly " aren't Included in the Project"? Did the changes are previously in project with feature branch. If so, it should also be there in Dev branch if all of files merges properly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay everyone. I'musing TFVC

Comment: @DanielMann I'm using TFVC with server workspace. @ PatrickLu-MSFT Sometimes the added files show up gray'ed out and I have ti manually "Include In Solution"

Comment: If you are seeing the files greyed out, then you have the files locally but they are not part of a project. Solutions wont show you any greyed out files (usually, VS 2017 always has an evil surprise hiding for us. The original merge not working correctly - and not reporting an error - could have been one of them for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you are doing the right process of merging in TFS(for example through VS):

1.In **Source Control Explorer**, select the second branch that you want to merge.

2.Click the File menu, point to Source Control, point to **Branching and Merging**, and then click **Merge**.The **Source Control Merge Wizard** will displayed.

3.In the **Target branch** drop-down list, select the target team project branch  to which you want to merge the source branch(first branch).

4.Select the range of changes that you want to merge into the target branch by selecting either the **All changes up to a specific version** or **Selected changesets option**, and click Next.

5.Click **Next**, and then on the **Perform the merge operation** page, click **Finish**. One or more pending changes are generated.

Finally check in the pending changes if there are no conflicts to solve. After merged performed, you could see the same folder levels/files in Dev Branch the same as Feature branch.

If you want to show the files/folders that aren't included in the project before the merge, you could use the **compare** feature, just select the changeset before merge and merge changeset do the compare, it will show all changes.